I am using Azure Open AI through databricks. Facing Timeout issue for below code. I am using GPT-4. Whats wrong here?
import os
from openai import AzureOpenAI


client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint = "https://az*****.openai.azure.com/", 
  api_key=OPEN_AI_KEY,  
  api_version="2024-02-15-preview"
)


message_text = [{"role":"system","content":"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."}]

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-4-1106-Preview", # model = "deployment_name"
  messages = message_text,
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=800,
  top_p=0.95,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
  timeout = 120,
  stop=None
)


Error : APITimeoutError: Request timed out.


Tried by changing API keys, earlier the same code was running smoothly. Don't know how to check logs, where Azure Open AI is not reachable or Databricks failed to make a call. Need a help to resolve this.

You are not having the stable network or if there is any downtime in your deployed model gives you this error.
In such situation you are giving the timeout only 120 seconds which gives you the error.
Usually it takes about 3-4 seconds to connect but in your case it's taking more than 120 seconds so keep the default timeout that is 10 minutes and check it works.
Additionally, stabilize your network and check model deployment once.
I got time out error when i given 1 and 2 seconds, so you need to give some time to make connection.
